# Not display bold content in webview android

Tags: android

I have set custom font in Webview using

```
String html = "<html><head><title></title> "
            + "<style type=\"text/css\"> "
            + "@font-face { font-family:'GEORGIA'; src: url('file:///android_asset/GEORGIA.TTF'); }"
            + "body { font-family: 'GEORGIA'; text-align: justify;}"
            + "</style> "
            + "</head><body >"
            + "<div>"
            + "<p>"
            + data + "</p></div></body></html>";

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("",html,"text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

It is set font but problem is that in data i have text like **heading** contents when i run it then heading is not display bold.

Comment: Strange... working with `String data = "<h1>Hi there</h1>, how are you?";` in a fresh android-studio project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your font does not contain **bold** characters.
True Type Fonts (TTF) can contain a subset of all available characters.

Did you copy the ttf-file from your systems fontpath?
If not, you can open the font with a tool like [font-explorer](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/),